# SSH Automatic login With Floating Profile

Tags: ssh

I've a floating profile on a server. There's no local account. All machines load same profile. I tried to use public key for automatic login without any luck. Is there any way to automatically login without password? I'm a standard user. 
Currently I use a loop to open all machines in a separate shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=62; i<=71; i++))
do  
    gnome-terminal -e "ssh mf-f3-$i" #machine name start with mf-f3-*
done
```

Then I have to enter the password in all the shells. I don't want that. I want automatic login.

Comment: we will probably need some more information what is the error you are getting when you are logging in with the public key. There will be some error on the server side log, that should tell you more.

Comment: It's not recognizing public keys, just keeps on asking password.

Comment: By 'floating profile' do you mean nfs or cifs or something else?  What's the output of 'mount | grep <username>' or 'mount | grep home'.

Comment: I have one profile over the network. We don't have local accounts. So when I log into any machine it loads same profile everywhere.

Comment: Yes, it's nfs. The output of 'mount | grep <username>' is none. And output of mount | grep home is
mainframevfx:/ifs/data/systems/home on /home type nfs (rw,noatime,nodiratime,nolock,addr=10.1.24.124)

Answer (score 1):

Did you deploy your ssh key on all of the target servers ?

Usually you have to put your public key into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file of the target server in order for him to recognise you and bypass the password auth.

Second, do you have an ssh-agent running on your local computer and loader your key in it ? (ssh-agent; ssh-add).

Comment: I've single home directory(~/) so all machine should have ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Comment: are the permission on authorized_keys correct ? (only rw for U and nothing for other/group)

Comment: It looks like login using public keys is disabled by root in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Comment: # Authentication:
#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10
#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no

Comment: # Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes
# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes
# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

Comment: Is there any way without involving root in it.

Comment: If editing /etc/ssh/sshd_condif is required then root must be involved, unless normal user has write access on the file.